# Operation '' is not defined in the WSDL for this service

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

Im trying to make this fixed, but im stuck. Im not very skilled with WSDL, SOAP and making an XML with it. I'll keep getting this error "Operation '' is not defined in the WSDL for this service" Did anyone know how did i get rid of this error? My goal is to get an XML with all the occasions from a car garage and put them in my database.

This is my code:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 1);

$options = array(
   'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
   'trace'      => true,
   'exceptions' => true,
   'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
   'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
   'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_DISK,
   'login' => '****',     // <- username here, i got the right one
   'password' => '****'  // <- same
);

try{
   $client = new SoapClient('https://eigenwebsite.doorlinkenvoorraad.nl/v1/leads/deliver.html?wsdl', $options);

//var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
//echo '<br>';

$klant = array(
    "key"=>"****", // got the right one
    "klantnummer"=>"****", // got the right one
    "lead"=>"information_request",
    "testmode"=>"dummy"
);

$quote = $client->deliverLead($klant);

}catch(SoapFault $exception){
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Is this method "deliverLead" in the WSDL ?

Comment: Yep. I found it by the "__getFunctions" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the SOAP version to 1.1:

```
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
```

The web service only supports SOAP 1.1 from the looks of the WSDL, so it is throwing an error when you send it a SOAP 1.2 message.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue, and it was fixed by ensuring that my content type was set to `text/xml`.

In Postman, selecting the `Raw` body option with `XML` will auto-set your content type to `application/xml`, which will give you this operation not defined error. In this case, go to the headers tab, uncheck the `Content-Type` checkbox, and manually enter a new value for `Content-Type` = `text/xml`.